Convert space coordinates
I have a python code I use to guess points in a airspace. It works very well. I am using a txt file where points are with their coordinates. At present points are identified by this kind of coordinates:
BORAS 770 624.
What I need is to do the same but using an other txt file where points have geografical reference like this:
BORAS 441327N 0100414E.
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox, Canvas
import os

# Funzione per leggere le parole e le coordinate dal file coordinate_punti.txt
def load_words_from_file(filename):
    if os.path.exists(filename):
        with open(filename, 'r') as file:
            lines = file.readlines()
            words = []
            for line in lines:
                parts = line.split()
                if len(parts) >= 3:  # Verifica che ci siano almeno 3 elementi
                    word = parts[0].strip().lower()  # La parola è il primo elemento
                    try:
                        # Recupera le coordinate e converte in interi
                        coordinates = (int(parts[1]), int(parts[2]))  
                        words.append((word, coordinates))  # Aggiungi parola e coordinate come tuple
                    except ValueError:
                        messagebox.showwarning("Errore", f"Coordinate non valide per la parola '{word}'")
                else:
                    messagebox.showwarning("Errore", "Formato non valido nella riga: " + line)
            return words
    else:
        messagebox.showerror("Errore", f"Il file {filename} non esiste!")
        return []

# Funzione per normalizzare le coordinate
def normalize_coordinates(words_data, canvas_width=600, canvas_height=450):
    # Estrai le coordinate
    x_values = [coord[1] for _, coord in words_data]
    y_values = [coord[0] for _, coord in words_data]

    # Trova i valori massimi e minimi
    x_min, x_max = min(x_values), max(x_values)
    y_min, y_max = min(y_values), max(y_values)

    # Normalizza le coordinate
    normalized_words = []
    for word, (x, y) in words_data:
        # Normalizzazione
        x_normalized = ((x - x_min) / (x_max - x_min) * (canvas_width - 40) + 20) - 50  # Centrare verso sinistra
        y_normalized = (y - y_min) / (y_max - y_min) * (canvas_height - 40) + 20
        normalized_words.append((word, (int(x_normalized), int(y_normalized))))

    return normalized_words

# Percorso multipiattaforma del file coordinate_punti.txt
file_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'coordinate_punti.txt')

# Carica le parole e le coordinate dal file
words_data = load_words_from_file(file_path)

# Normalizza le coordinate mantenendo le proporzioni
normalized_words_data = normalize_coordinates(words_data)

class WordGameApp:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Points")

        if not normalized_words_data:  # Se la lista di parole è vuota
            self.root.quit()
            return

        self.initialize_game()

        # Frame principale
        self.frame = tk.Frame(root)
        self.frame.pack(pady=10)

        # Label per le istruzioni
        self.label = tk.Label(self.frame, text="Inserisci i punti che ricordi:")
        self.label.pack(pady=10)

        # Textbox per l'inserimento della parola
        self.word_entry = tk.Entry(self.frame)
        self.word_entry.pack(pady=10)
        self.word_entry.bind('<Return>', self.check_word)  # Tasto Enter per invio parola

        # Label per il contatore di parole
        self.counter_label = tk.Label(self.frame, text=f"Punti restanti: {self.remaining_words}")
        self.counter_label.pack(pady=10)

        # Canvas per disegnare forme
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.frame, width=600, height=400)
        self.canvas.pack(pady=10)

        # Pulsante per pulire il canvas e resettare la sessione
        self.clear_button = tk.Button(self.frame, text="Pulisci e Reset", command=self.reset_game)
        self.clear_button.pack(pady=10)

        # Pulsante per mostrare/nascondere tutte le parole
        self.toggle_button = tk.Button(self.frame, text="Mostra tutti i punti", command=self.toggle_words)
        self.toggle_button.pack(pady=10)

        # Frame separato per i pulsanti orizzontali
        self.button_frame = tk.Frame(self.frame)
        self.button_frame.pack(pady=10)  # Aggiungi il frame

In the code above, coordinates are also normalized so that all the points in the list can be showed within the Canvas also when I use the script on my phone.

What is your question?

How can I use the new coordinates format?

You seem to have spherical co-ordinates (eg 441327N, which may represent either 44deg13min27secNorth or 44deg13,27min North - which are different locations). These are points in 3-D space on a surface around the spherical center. You seem to want to project this point onto a 2-D canvas so your need to be clear what this means as various projections are possible just as for showing the Earth on a paper map. There is lots of information you can look up on using Python with, for example, Mercator Projections.

The geographical coordinates are in WGS84.
